# Use gtag events as trigger for tags in tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer, gtag.js, custom-events

I am able to see which event on are being triggered and sent to GA4 in gtm preview mode but I am not able to use all these events as triggers in gtm. I can only able to use events which are triggered on GTM-XXXXX data layer as custom event trigger but not on G-XXXXX data layer. How to use datalayer events of G-XXXX in gtm as trigger?